# What is the default admin password for DRONE_ADMIN users?

Tags: docker, drone.io

On first installation using a docker-compose file and following the [installation instructions](http://readme.drone.io/admin/installation-guide/) what is the default password for [Closed Registration](http://readme.drone.io/admin/user-registration) DRONE_ADMIN users?

The web frontend won't let you access it without a logon and it's not possible to create new users using the CLI without a login either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The administrative user needs to login with the Gogs username and password

> Drone will prompt you for a username and password to authenticate. You
>   should use your Gogs username and password. This is unfortunately
>   required due to Gogs lack of oauth2 support.

Let's use this example configuration for reference:

```
DRONE_ADMIN=johnsmith
```

You need to make sure that `johnsmith` is a valid Gogs username. When you are prompted to login you should enter `johnsmith` for the username, and use `johnsmith`'s Gogs password.

Comment: Thanks Brad it was the DRONE_ADMIN user == GOGs user that got me, I had put in DRONE_GOGS_GIT_USERNAME and DRONE_GOGS_GIT_PASSWORD so thought that would get me through. Out of interest gogs has configuration for setting up webhooks to push to a url, with secret etc. not sure if that can be used. Currently drone isn't picking up the push to gogs ... I may shift to gitlab.

Comment: Yes, drone automatically adds webhooks to your gogs repository when you active the repository in the drone user interface. I personally use gogs+drone and can confirm drone receives webhooks without issue. I would also say drone+gogs works better than drone+gitlab because gogs contributors actively work on drone.

Comment: I really thought it hadn't been hooking the webhooks up ... but with gogs always have to hard refresh the browser and there they are. Problem is self signed certificate not let through. Let's hope it all works after that.  Thanks for the help.